# Android GPS Result Format

Tags: android, formatting, gps, double, decimal

I have noticed with testing GPS locations, a value such as −123 might come up on Android as −23.83333336. Is there any way to format incoming GPS locations, such as within two decimal points?

This way I can store values like −123.83 opposed to longer numeric values. I have checked out `DecimalFormat` and `NumberFormat`, but these are strings and my numbers are doubles, and I cannot find a better way.

And does anyone know a maximum value of a location in numeric values? Knowing that, I can do something like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.##");
```

knowing the highest number is in the thousands, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function like this will round it without converting to a string:

```
public static final double roundDouble(double d, int places) {
    return Math.round(d * Math.pow(10, (double) places)) / Math.pow(10,
        (double) places);
}
```

For instance `roundDouble(502.23525, 2)` will produce 502.24

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply it by one hundred and store it in an integer if you're trying to replicate a fixed-precision number.